# Android - Setting up a splash screen

Tags: java, android

In my app, there are some time-taking processes in the `onCreate` method. Right now, the user sees a black screen until the data is loaded and is ready to be displayed. How can I add some sort of splash screen that says "Data is Loading" while the processes take place? 
Thanks

**EDIT** : I tried putting `setContentView(R.layout.splash_layout)` at the start of `onCreate` but it had no effect.

Comment: Tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/

Answer (score 1):

Create splash activity with some sort of image in layout background. Here in `onResume` start [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or just thread to do your time consumable operation. When task would be finished  just start your "Main" activity.